# IntelliJ JUnit 5 test run fine as Gradle task. When run as individual test sometimes get exception: NoClassDefFoundError .../TestExecutionListener

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, junit5

Using IntelliJ IDEA version 2018.2.5 (Community Edition) on Windows 10 and learning how to use JUnit 5 [parameterized tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) with Gradle 4.8 based on [JUnit 5 samples](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples) from the JUnit team.

The test run as expected as gradle task **test** but sometimes when running individual test get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
   org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
```

How can this exception be fixed while still using IntelliJ 2018.2.5 (Community Edition), JUnit 5 with parameter test and using Gradle?

I have been trying to find an answer for this but most of what I run into are answers that note the use of IntellJ with JUnit 5 are in a lot of transition so not sure what to trust.

### Details

I know there is way more detail and screen shots than normal or beyond normal, but when you are learning something new and need help and you start looking for info, you get tired of seeing answers that leave out some important detail. So for those that are in the same boat and need to see that missing detail hopefully I have included it here. While this question may not be the one you seek, the details here may help you.

**The exception stack trace**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.createListeners(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:45)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.launcher.TestExecutionListener
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 13 more
```

**Software Versions**

Microsoft Windows Version 10.0.171314.345

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.5 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-182.4892.20, build on October 16, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b19 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Project SDK: 11 (java version "11.0.1")
IntelliJ is clean version installed for this example.

Specific JUnit sample used: [junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle)

Gradle: 4.8

[build.gradle](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle/build.gradle) - exactly same as in demo

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse' // optional (to generate Eclipse project files)
    id 'idea' // optional (to generate IntelliJ IDEA project files)
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
    testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.1')
    testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '4.8'
}
```

Gradle runner: `Platform Test Runner`

[image]

### Steps used to build project

Downloaded [junit5-samples](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples)
Uncompressed files
Under directory `junit5-samples-r5.3.1` copied `junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle` to `C:\Users\Eric\IdeaProjects`

Used IntelliJ **Import Project** on welcome screen to load project.

[image]
[image]

Took default options for Import Project dialog options, e.g. click 'Next' or 'Finish' for all `Import Project` dialog pages.

```
C:.
|   .gitignore
|   build-JITPACK.gradle
|   build-SNAPSHOT.gradle
|   build.gradle
|   gradlew
|   gradlew.bat
|   README.md
|
+---.idea
|   |   misc.xml
|   |   modules.xml
|   |   workspace.xml
|   |
|   \---libraries
|           gradle_wrapper.xml
|
+---gradle
|   \---wrapper
|           gradle-wrapper.jar
|           gradle-wrapper.properties
|
\---src
    +---main
    |   |   main.iml
    |   |
    |   \---java
    |       \---com
    |           \---example
    |               \---project
    |                       Calculator.java
    |
    \---test
        |   test.iml
        |
        \---java
            \---com
                \---example
                    \---project
                            CalculatorTests.java
```

When project opened received Event log about `Unlinked Gradle project` and clicked `Import Gradle project`

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
C:.
|   .gitignore
|   build-JITPACK.gradle
|   build-SNAPSHOT.gradle
|   build.gradle
|   gradlew
|   gradlew.bat
|   README.md
|
+---.gradle
|   +---4.8
|   |   +---fileChanges
|   |   |       last-build.bin
|   |   |
|   |   \---fileHashes
|   |           fileHashes.lock
|   |
|   \---vcsWorkingDirs
|           gc.properties
|
+---.idea
|   |   compiler.xml
|   |   gradle.xml
|   |   misc.xml
|   |   modules.xml
|   |   workspace.xml
|   |
|   +---libraries
|   |       gradle_wrapper.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_apiguardian_apiguardian_api_1_0_0.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_api_5_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_engine_5_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_params_5_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_platform_junit_platform_commons_1_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_platform_junit_platform_engine_1_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_opentest4j_opentest4j_1_1_1.xml
|   |
|   \---modules
|           junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle.iml
|           junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle_main.iml
|           junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle_test.iml
|
+---gradle
|   \---wrapper
|           gradle-wrapper.jar
|           gradle-wrapper.properties
|
\---src
    +---main
    |   |   main.iml
    |   |
    |   \---java
    |       \---com
    |           \---example
    |               \---project
    |                       Calculator.java
    |
    \---test
        |   test.iml
        |
        \---java
            \---com
                \---example
                    \---project
                            CalculatorTests.java
```

Built project using Gradle task: build

[image]

```
C:.
|   .gitignore
|   build-JITPACK.gradle
|   build-SNAPSHOT.gradle
|   build.gradle
|   gradlew
|   gradlew.bat
|   README.md
|
+---.gradle
|   +---4.8
|   |   +---fileChanges
|   |   |       last-build.bin
|   |   |
|   |   +---fileContent
|   |   |       annotation-processors.bin
|   |   |       fileContent.lock
|   |   |
|   |   +---fileHashes
|   |   |       fileHashes.bin
|   |   |       fileHashes.lock
|   |   |       resourceHashesCache.bin
|   |   |
|   |   \---taskHistory
|   |           taskHistory.bin
|   |           taskHistory.lock
|   |
|   +---buildOutputCleanup
|   |       buildOutputCleanup.lock
|   |       cache.properties
|   |       outputFiles.bin
|   |
|   \---vcsWorkingDirs
|           gc.properties
|
+---.idea
|   |   compiler.xml
|   |   gradle.xml
|   |   misc.xml
|   |   modules.xml
|   |   workspace.xml
|   |
|   +---libraries
|   |       gradle_wrapper.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_apiguardian_apiguardian_api_1_0_0.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_api_5_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_engine_5_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_jupiter_junit_jupiter_params_5_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_platform_junit_platform_commons_1_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_junit_platform_junit_platform_engine_1_3_1.xml
|   |       Gradle__org_opentest4j_opentest4j_1_1_1.xml
|   |
|   \---modules
|           junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle.iml
|           junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle_main.iml
|           junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle_test.iml
|
+---build
|   +---classes
|   |   \---java
|   |       +---main
|   |       |   \---com
|   |       |       \---example
|   |       |           \---project
|   |       |                   Calculator.class
|   |       |
|   |       \---test
|   |           \---com
|   |               \---example
|   |                   \---project
|   |                           CalculatorTests.class
|   |
|   +---libs
|   |       junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle.jar
|   |
|   +---reports
|   |   \---tests
|   |       \---test
|   |           |   index.html
|   |           |
|   |           +---classes
|   |           |       com.example.project.CalculatorTests.html
|   |           |
|   |           +---css
|   |           |       base-style.css
|   |           |       style.css
|   |           |
|   |           +---js
|   |           |       report.js
|   |           |
|   |           \---packages
|   |                   com.example.project.html
|   |
|   +---test-results
|   |   \---test
|   |       |   TEST-com.example.project.CalculatorTests.xml
|   |       |
|   |       \---binary
|   |               output.bin
|   |               output.bin.idx
|   |               results.bin
|   |
|   \---tmp
|       +---compileJava
|       +---compileTestJava
|       \---jar
|               MANIFEST.MF
|
+---gradle
|   \---wrapper
|           gradle-wrapper.jar
|           gradle-wrapper.properties
|
\---src
    +---main
    |   |   main.iml
    |   |
    |   \---java
    |       \---com
    |           \---example
    |               \---project
    |                       Calculator.java
    |
    \---test
        |   test.iml
        |
        \---java
            \---com
                \---example
                    \---project
                            CalculatorTests.java
```

**Files cached by Gradle**

```
C:\Users\Eric\.gradle\caches>tree modules-2 /A /F

C:\USERS\ERIC\.GRADLE\CACHES\MODULES-2
|   modules-2.lock
|
+---files-2.1
|   +---org.apiguardian
|   |   \---apiguardian-api
|   |       \---1.0.0
|   |           +---2c4e5835b7580f2696be7ee1402f4309b3665cf4
|   |           |       apiguardian-api-1.0.0.pom
|   |           |
|   |           +---3ef5276905e36f4d8055fe3cb0bdcc7503ffc85d
|   |           |       apiguardian-api-1.0.0.jar
|   |           |
|   |           \---777508fa9f3e03cafb3c1fb2eba3dca317f4b1ee
|   |                   apiguardian-api-1.0.0-sources.jar
|   |
|   +---org.junit.jupiter
|   |   +---junit-jupiter-api
|   |   |   \---5.3.1
|   |   |       +---39e68334cdee95898567f54d7358a6926262dde6
|   |   |       |       junit-jupiter-api-5.3.1.pom
|   |   |       |
|   |   |       +---a7e97eac2784395cb991403f9641b042ad972941
|   |   |       |       junit-jupiter-api-5.3.1.jar
|   |   |       |
|   |   |       \---b03f607c0822a283c972e37eaeacb00dc3a3c2e7
|   |   |               junit-jupiter-api-5.3.1-sources.jar
|   |   |
|   |   +---junit-jupiter-engine
|   |   |   \---5.3.1
|   |   |       +---c769957170b2240854d6da6c6706dcc2a281542f
|   |   |       |       junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1-sources.jar
|   |   |       |
|   |   |       +---e0b10da40cae904d69b805021bc1f5d64994aa93
|   |   |       |       junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.pom
|   |   |       |
|   |   |       \---e2676b1786c57a80eb98f5bebd51a3d05e228c40
|   |   |               junit-jupiter-engine-5.3.1.jar
|   |   |
|   |   \---junit-jupiter-params
|   |       \---5.3.1
|   |           +---9dfac3fbd6768974fc0c142304a3e90ba713b2a8
|   |           |       junit-jupiter-params-5.3.1.jar
|   |           |
|   |           +---bc4eb2ef307286fcd45551d4da397518c2e15394
|   |           |       junit-jupiter-params-5.3.1-sources.jar
|   |           |
|   |           \---cf0c573f1a0446afb8d544a5fd53dae4bb433b79
|   |                   junit-jupiter-params-5.3.1.pom
|   |
|   +---org.junit.platform
|   |   +---junit-platform-commons
|   |   |   \---1.3.1
|   |   |       +---297bb35bca3d229c5e6edbffd22de7b5ad4cf430
|   |   |       |       junit-platform-commons-1.3.1-sources.jar
|   |   |       |
|   |   |       +---67b7edddfac1935e6e6d9b58d7c7df6db59b1d39
|   |   |       |       junit-platform-commons-1.3.1.jar
|   |   |       |
|   |   |       \---c47714600308339d4b5e203974ebd2ce50eb2109
|   |   |               junit-platform-commons-1.3.1.pom
|   |   |
|   |   \---junit-platform-engine
|   |       \---1.3.1
|   |           +---3ee68a06bbdab157dd260e2095c356481d6cd172
|   |           |       junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.jar
|   |           |
|   |           +---db2bf7e793fec08aed5c588eb495595e4acc9fc7
|   |           |       junit-platform-engine-1.3.1.pom
|   |           |
|   |           \---effe038ffcf21f6988e78b12119ca456d7d144fd
|   |                   junit-platform-engine-1.3.1-sources.jar
|   |
|   \---org.opentest4j
|       \---opentest4j
|           \---1.1.1
|               +---6554a839d3c3f1c77c593498a3ae4b692878946a
|               |       opentest4j-1.1.1.pom
|               |
|               +---88a3a2cb15c413565462cea99f201b67bc6d2f10
|               |       opentest4j-1.1.1-sources.jar
|               |
|               \---efd9f971e91074491ea55b19f67b13470cf4fcdd
|                       opentest4j-1.1.1.jar
|
\---metadata-2.58
    |   module-artifact.bin
    |   module-artifacts.bin
    |   module-metadata.bin
    |   resource-at-url.bin
    |
    \---descriptors
        +---org.apiguardian
        |   \---apiguardian-api
        |       \---1.0.0
        |           \---f8e6315c37eb56998f7a5ba08e30db71
        |                   descriptor.bin
        |
        +---org.junit.jupiter
        |   +---junit-jupiter-api
        |   |   \---5.3.1
        |   |       \---f8e6315c37eb56998f7a5ba08e30db71
        |   |               descriptor.bin
        |   |
        |   +---junit-jupiter-engine
        |   |   \---5.3.1
        |   |       \---f8e6315c37eb56998f7a5ba08e30db71
        |   |               descriptor.bin
        |   |
        |   \---junit-jupiter-params
        |       \---5.3.1
        |           \---f8e6315c37eb56998f7a5ba08e30db71
        |                   descriptor.bin
        |
        +---org.junit.platform
        |   +---junit-platform-commons
        |   |   \---1.3.1
        |   |       \---f8e6315c37eb56998f7a5ba08e30db71
        |   |               descriptor.bin
        |   |
        |   \---junit-platform-engine
        |       \---1.3.1
        |           \---f8e6315c37eb56998f7a5ba08e30db71
        |                   descriptor.bin
        |
        \---org.opentest4j
            \---opentest4j
                \---1.1.1
                    \---f8e6315c37eb56998f7a5ba08e30db71
                            descriptor.bin
```

Closed panel on right
Using `Project` panel on left
Expand directories to reveal `test/java/com.example.project/CalculatorTests.java`
Double clicked `CalculatorTests.java`

[image]

To fix first error put cursor on `Assertions` on line 13 and press `ALT+Enter`
Click first option

```
Add library 'Gradle: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1' to classpath
```

To fix second error put cursor on `ParameterizedTest` on line 17 and press `ALT+Enter`
Click first option

```
Add library 'Gradle: org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.3.1' to classpath
```

To fix third error put cursor on `Calculator` on line 26 and press `ALT+Enter`
Click first option

```
Add dependency on module 'main'
```

[image]

[image]

Then under Gradle tab ran `verification` -> `test` which successfully returned expected results

```
Testing started at 2:56 PM ...
2:56:07 PM: Executing task 'test'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes
> Task :compileTestJava
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test
com.example.project.CalculatorTests > addsTwoNumbers() PASSED
com.example.project.CalculatorTests > add(int, int, int)[1] PASSED
com.example.project.CalculatorTests > add(int, int, int)[2] PASSED
com.example.project.CalculatorTests > add(int, int, int)[3] PASSED
com.example.project.CalculatorTests > add(int, int, int)[4] PASSED
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 6s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
2:56:13 PM: Task execution finished 'test'.
```

[image]

[image]

Then when running individual test in CalculatorTest.java by clicking on green arrow in left margin and selecting `Run 'addsTowNumbers()'` received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
   org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
```

[image]

[image]

### EDIT

### Now individual test work

Yesterday I saved the project and then loaded up the [Maven sample](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven) which also failed. When I woke up today I and decided to tinker with the Gradle sample some more. When I clicked on the arrow in the left margin for a single test it worked this time. The only reason at present I can think of for why it works now is that in running the Maven sample something was changed, or in closing and reopening the project something changed.

CalculatorTest.java

```
/*
 * Copyright 2015-2018 the original author or authors.
 *
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials are
 * made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v2.0 which
 * accompanies this distribution and is available at
 *
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v20.html
 */

package com.example.project;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

class CalculatorTests {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("1 + 1 = 2")
    void addsTwoNumbers() {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        assertEquals(2, calculator.add(1, 1), "1 + 1 should equal 2");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest(name = "{0} + {1} = {2}")
    @CsvSource({
            "0,    1,   1",
            "1,    2,   3",
            "49,  51, 100",
            "1,  100, 101"
    })
    void add(int first, int second, int expectedResult) {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        assertEquals(expectedResult, calculator.add(first, second),
                () -> first + " + " + second + " should equal " + expectedResult);
    }
}
```

Result of running test for line 20: `class CalculatorTests {`

[image]

[image]

Result of running test for line 24: `void addsTwoNumbers() {`

[image]

[image]

Result of running test for line 36: `void add(int first, int second, int expectedResult) {`

[image]

[image]

Result of running Gradle task: `test`

[image]

[image]

### The selected test matters

There are two [Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html) created for `CalculatorTests`

1. `CalculatorTests` has `Use classpath of module:` with `test` and throws the exception.
2. `CalculatorTests (1)` has `Use classpath of module:` with `junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle_test` and completes successfully.

Comment: According to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188678, it's a problem of JUnit itself, not IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks. Reading it now.

Comment: Of intereset: [JUnit parameterized tests](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206270229-JUnit-parameterized-tests)

Comment: Of interest: [Unable to execute single parameterized JUnit test](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-184683) - issue IDEA-184683

Comment: Of interest: [IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 Help - Configuration tab](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html#configTab)

Comment: Of interest: [Gradle - The IDEA Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Gradle - The Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Gradle - Dependency Management for Java Projects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_for_java_projects.html)

Comment: Of interest: [JUnit - "Test events were not received" and other issues under IntelliJ #804](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/804)

Comment: Of interest: [Microsoft DOS command - tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree)

Comment: Of interest: [Gradle docs - section - test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Gradle docs - section - testLogging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.htmll)

Comment: Or interest: [JUnit5 - Annotation Type Testable](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/commons/annotation/Testable.html) - Motivation for `@Testable` - Some clients of the JUnit Platform, notably IDEs such as IntelliJ IDEA, operate only on sources for test discovery. Thus, they cannot use the full runtime discovery mechanism of the JUnit Platform since it relies on compiled classes. `@Testable` therefore serves as an alternative mechanism for IDEs to discover tests by analyzing the source code only.

Comment: Of interest: [JUnit5 -Extension Model](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions) - Overview - In contrast to the competing `Runner`, `@Rule`, and `@ClassRule` extension points in JUnit 4, the JUnit Jupiter extension model consists of a single, coherent concept: the Extension API. Note, however, that Extension itself is just a marker interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA (for this question Community 2018.2) will sometimes generate an invalid configuration for a JUnit5 test.

To see the run configuration from the menu choose: Run -> Edit Configurations...

[image]

### Two different results

In this example there are two run configurations for Class CalculatorTests generated by IntelliJ IDEA.

### 1.

The first configuration generates the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   
  org/junit/platform/launcher/TestExecutionListener
```

[image]

[image]

### 2.

The second configuration runs correctly

[image]

[image]

### Summary

So when running individual test by clicking on the green arrow in the left margin and the test results in an exception. Check which configuration is actually running

[image]

and then check the configuration details for the test

[image]

to make sure `Use classpath or module` is set correctly.