# Neo4j can't seem to find a match for a simple path pattern when it should

Tags: neo4j, pattern-matching, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying some neo4j (3.4.9) and I have a query that I think should work but strangely doesn't.

The first two queries do work (as shown). Their results would suggest to me that the third should at least return one result, and yet it returns none.

Why does the third query not work as I expect it to?

```
neo4j> MATCH (s:Station {name: "Old Street"})-[:IN_REGION]->(r:Region)
       RETURN r.name,s.name;
+-------------------------+
| r.name   | S.name       |
+-------------------------+
| "London" | "Old Street" |
+-------------------------+

1 row available after 24 ms, consumed after another 3 ms
neo4j> MATCH (s:Station {name: "Limehouse"})-[:IN_REGION]->(r:Region)    
       RETURN r.name,s.name;
+------------------------+
| r.name   | s.name      |
+------------------------+
| "London" | "Limehouse" |
+------------------------+

1 row available after 22 ms, consumed after another 3 ms
neo4j> MATCH (a:Station {name: "Old Street"})-[:IN_REGION]->(r:Region)<-[:IN_REGION]-(b:Station)
       RETURN r.name,a.name,b.name;
0 rows available after 41 ms, consumed after another 2 ms
neo4j>
```

I'd expect to see (at least) the "Old Street" - "London" - "Limehouse" match returned.

Thanks.

-- Wrote up and accepted the solution proposed by Dave Bennett and Guy Coder.

Comment: Try the same query but use `-` instead of `->` or `<-`.

Comment: Can you try `MATCH (r:Region {name: 'London'}) RETURN count(r) AS londons`

Comment: @GuyCoder Thanks for the reply
```neo4j> MATCH (a:Station {name: "Old Street"})-[:IN_REGION]-(r:Region)-[:IN_REGION]-(b:Station) RETURN r.name,a.name,b.name;

0 rows available after 23 ms, consumed after another 3 ms

neo4j>
```
Doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: @DaveBennett That query returns the following:

```neo4j> MATCH (r:Region {name: 'London'}) RETURN count(r) AS londons;
+---------+
| londons |
+---------+
| 330     |
+---------+

1 row available after 17 ms, consumed after another 0 ms```
Apologies for the terrible formatting, it seems that code excerpts doesn't work quite as nicely in comments.

Comment: np, so if I am reading that correctly it looks like you have 330 different region node named _*"London"*_. I would have expected a single region Node (or a few given there are many Londons) but not 330. I would say that it is likely that "Old Street" and "Limehouse" are connected to different nodes named "London".

Comment: Dave's previous comment seems to be on the right track. Out of curiosity what does searching for a path return, `MATCH (n:Station {name: "Old Street"}),(m:Station {name: "Limehouse"}),p=shortestPath((n)-[r*]-(m)) 
RETURN n.name,p,m.name;` This may not be a valid query, but it should be close to being correct.

Comment: If some of the responses you need to put in comments don't work well or fit in the comments, then you can edit your question by adding a new section, note the comment, then add the response into the original question. Makes life easier for everyone. :)

Comment: Dave was correct, the issue was that when I was loading the data from CSV I used CREATE to build the nodes when I should have been using MERGE. There were then some issues with nulls which were fixed by using the coalesce function, then deleting nodes marked as having undefined properties by that call. After doing that, there were much fewer nodes overall, and the query worked as expected! Thank you guys. I will put a small write up in the question too for others.

Comment: You need to move the answer from your question into an answer and then accept it as the answer, this way others will see that it has an accepted answer, read the question, read the answer and possibly give you some upvotes. There is nothing wrong with posting an answer to your question as long as you don't immediately post the answer after asking the question.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52972457/1243762) is an example where I ask the question then answered it a few days latter after finding the answer.

Comment: Also if someone helps you out in the comments and doesn't get points for helping you, you can always search there other answers and upvote a few of them if they are worthy answers to return the favor.

Comment: Your answer should include some sample lines from the CSV file. You gave all of the details of the query but it helps to have data to go with it. If others find your question and need to learn from it, it helps to have everything one needs. :)

Comment: All sorted. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in how I was loading the data.

Previously, I loaded it using:

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///estimates-of-station-usage-2016-17.csv" AS line
CREATE stuff
However, this meant that many nodes were duplicated with the same properties, such that they were distinct but not immediately distinguishable.

To avoid this problem, use CREATE only for the nodes you know will be unique, then use MERGE to create nodes that will link other nodes together.

My CSV loading code changed to this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///estimates-of-station-usage-2016-17.csv" AS line
CREATE (s:Station {name: line.`Station Name` , entriesAndExits: toInteger(replace(trim(line.`1617 Entries & Exits`), ",", "")) })
MERGE (fo:FacilityOwner {name: coalesce(line.`Station Facility Owner`, "Unknown")})
MERGE (r:Region {name: coalesce(line.Region, "Unknown")})
MERGE (la:LocalAuthority {name: coalesce(line.`Local Authority`, "Unknown")})
MERGE (fo)-[:OWNS]->(s)
MERGE (la)-[:RESPONSIBLE_FOR]->(s)
MERGE (la)-[:IN]->(r)
MERGE (s)-[:IN]->(r)
MERGE (fo)-[:OPERATES_IN]->(r)
RETURN s,r,la,fo;

MATCH (s:Station)
WHERE NOT exists(s.name) OR NOT exists(s.entriesAndExits)
DETACH DELETE s
RETURN s;

MATCH (r:Region)
WHERE r.name = "Unknown"
DETACH DELETE r
RETURN r;

MATCH (fo:FacilityOwner)
WHERE fo.name = "Unknown"
DETACH DELETE fo
RETURN fo;

MATCH (la:LocalAuthority)
WHERE la.name = "Unknown"
DETACH DELETE la
RETURN la;
```

-- Thanks to Dave Bennett and Guy Coder for their helpful comments.

Side note on the CSV data in question:

The fields in the CSV file are all simple strings. There is a lot of code noise in parsing the entriesAndExits count for the stations because the entries of that column are numbers formatted as strings including excess whitespace and commas to separate groups of 3 digits, for example, " 546,123 ".